# Can every (convex) polygon be described by a single inequality (involving absolute values)?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, polygons

For example,

$$
|x| + |2x + y| + |x + 2y| + |y| + |x+y| < 4
$$
describes an octagon. I'm wondering whether an equation of this form always exist for any convex polygon, and if so, whether there is a systematic way to obtain it from a set of inequalities whose intersections form the polygon.

For example, this describes a square:

$$
y < x + 1 \cap y > x - 1 \cap y < -x + 1 \cap y > -x -1
$$

but this is the same as
$$
|x| + |y| < 1
$$

Is there a general procedure to get from the intersection form to a single equation?

Comment: How about a triangle? I.e. figure with no parallel edges.

Comment: I don't think parallelism matters. Here is one example for a triangle: $x + |y| < 3$. Edit: oops that is wrong!

Comment: $x+|y|<3$ defines, not a triangle, but an unbounded region, bounded by a vertex at $(3,0)$ from which two infinite rays depart, going NW and SW.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was fooled for a second. Randomly entering inequalities it seems that I always do get para-polygons if they are bounded... is this always the case?

Comment: The single inequality examples you've given use only sums of absolute values of linear combinations of the coordinates.  Geometrically that means embedding $\mathbb R^2$ in some $\mathbb R^n$ and taking its intersection with (a scaled copy of) the $\ell_1$ ball there.  You can get non-centrally-symmetric polygons if you use affine combinations of the coordinates; e.g., $|x|+|y|+|1-x-y|\le 1$ gives a triangle.

Comment: Hm... and I think that geometry might solve the problem, at least for centrally symmetric polygons.  Take the dual; it's again a centrally symmetric polygon, so it's a zonotope, that is, a projection of a higher-dimensional cube; so the original is a section of a higher-dimensional $\ell_1$, which is what we want.  This wouldn't work in higher dimensions, where not everything is a zonotope.

Comment: No idea about your question but I suspect it is doable. In case you know chinese, there is a [book](http://lpj.hit.edu.cn/xsyg_detail.asp?id=66) "绝对值方程——折边与组合图形的解析研究" (Absolute Value Equation - Analytical Research on Folding and Composite Figure) by two chinese which dedicate the whole book to study how to represent geometric figure using "absolute value equations". Next time when I go to bookstore, I'll see whether that book is still available. It will definitely contain every answer you want to know about this problem.

Comment: @achille hui It sounds like a wonderful book; unfortunately I don't ready Chinese!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $|t|+t$ is null on one side and positive on the other, so the inside of any convex polygon can be defined as

$$\sum_kw_k\left(|a_kx+b_ky+c_k|+a_kx+b_ky+c_k\right)\le0,$$
where the $w_k$ are positive weights and $(a_k,b_k,c_k)$ are the coefficients of the equations of the edges.

In addition, for a closed polygon you can always ensure that 
$$\sum_k w_ka_k=\sum_k w_kb_k=0.$$

For example, take the triangle through $(0,0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$, i.e sides $-x=0$, $-y=0$ and $x+y-1=0$ (LHS negative inside). Using equal weights,

$$|-x|+|-y|+|x+y-1|\le 1.$$

Comment: Thanks! This answer is neat and pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $3$ non-collinear points $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\Delta$ be the triangle with $A,B,C$ as vertices. Let $h_A, h_B, h_C$ be the heights of $\Delta$ for corresponding vertices. It is known that for any point $P$ on the plane, there exists a unique pair of real numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that

$$\vec{P} - \vec{C} = \alpha(\vec{A}-\vec{C}) + \beta(\vec{B} - \vec{C}) 
\quad\iff\quad \vec{P} = \alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + (1-\alpha-\beta)\vec{C}$$
Let $\gamma = 1 - \alpha - \beta$, the triplet $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is known as the baricentric coordinates of  point $P$ with respect to $\Delta$. In terms of $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, $P$ lies inside or on $\Delta$ when and only when 
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are all non-negative.

For any line $\ell \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, let $d(P,\ell)$ be the distance between the point $P$ and line $\ell$.

$$d(P,\ell) \stackrel{def}{=} \inf\big\{\; |\vec{P} - \vec{Q}| : Q \in \ell\; \big\}$$

Associate $\Delta$ with following function

$$f_{\Delta}(P) = \frac{1}{h_A} d(P,\overline{BC}) + \frac{1}{h_B} d(P,\overline{CA}) + \frac{1}{h_C}d(P,\overline{AB}) - 1$$

Notice
$$
|\alpha_P| h_A = d( P, \overline{BC} ),\quad
|\beta_P|  h_B = d( P, \overline{CA} ),\quad\text{ and }
|\gamma_P | h_C = d( P, \overline{AB} )
$$
We have 
$$f_\Delta(P) = |\alpha_P| + |\beta_P| + |\gamma_P| - 1
\ge \alpha_P + \beta_P + \gamma_P - 1 = 0$$
Furthermore, the inequality is strict unless $\alpha_P, \beta_P, \gamma_P \ge 0$ which in turn is equivalent to the condition $P \in \Delta$.

What this means is any non-degenerate triangle $\Delta$ can be represented as the level set for an absolute value equation $f_\Delta(P) = 0$.

Given any convex $n$-gon $X$, we know it can be represented as the intersection of $n$ half-planes $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_n$ whose supporting lines containing the corresponding side of $X$. 
$$X = \bigcap_{i=1}^n H_i$$
For each $H_i$, find a triangle $\Delta_i$ so that one of its side is lying on the corresponding support line and large enough to contain $X$. In this way, we can rewrite $X$ as

$$X = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \Delta_i$$

Let $f_X(P) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_{\Delta_i}(P)$. Since $f_{\Delta_i}(\cdot)$ are non-negative, so does $f_X(\cdot)$. It is easy to see

$$f_X(P) = 0 \iff f_{\Delta_i}(P) = 0, \forall i \iff P \in \Delta_i, \forall i \iff
P \in \bigcap_{i=1}^n \Delta_i = X$$

From this, we can conclude every convex $n$-gon $X$ can be written the level set of
an absolute value equation $f_X(P) = 0$ which contains at most $3n$ terms of absolute values of the from $|ax + by + c|$ plus one extra constant term.

Finally, as mentioned in the comment, the best reference of this topic is probably
following [book](http://lpj.hit.edu.cn/xsyg_detail.asp?id=66):

- 绝对值方程——折边与组合图形的解析研究
  (Absolute Value Equation - Analytical Research on Folding and Composite Figure)
  author: 林世保, 楊世明.
  publisher: 哈爾濱工業大學出版社.
  ISBN, 9787560335124

and the two authors dedicate the whole book to study how to represent geometric figures using "absolute value equations".

**Update**

Thinking more about this, there is a much simpler solution!

Given any convex $n$-gon $X$ with vertices $(x_1,y_2)$, $(x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_n,y_n)$, 
ordered counter-clockwisely around $X$ as a region. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the area of $X$ and $(x_0,y_0) = (x_n,y_n)$.

For every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, define the function

$$A_k(x,y) \stackrel{def}{=} \frac12\left|\begin{matrix} 1 & x & y\\ 1 & x_{k-1} & y_{k-1} \\ 1 & x_k & y_k\end{matrix}\right|$$

It is clear

1. $|A_k(x,y)|$ is the area of the triangle with vertices $(x,y), (x_{k-1},y_{k-1}), (x_k,y_k)$.
2. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n A_k(x,y) = \mathcal{A}$.
3. $A_k(x,y) \ge 0$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is on the same side of $X$ with respect to the edge joining $(x_{k-1},y_{k-1})$ to $(x_k,y_k)$.

What this means is for all $(x,y)$, we have
$\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=1}^n |A_k(x,y)| \ge \mathcal{A}$.
Furthermore, $X$ is the level set for the absolute value equation
$\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=1}^n |A_k(x,y)| = \mathcal{A}\;$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have to spend some time going through it, a lot of it I don't understand.